# Serve static file from within a group with Gin

Tags: go, go-gin, go-http

I want to server static file by mapping `/fs` to `filesys` in the disk. I can server static file like this:

```
r := gin.New()
r.Use(static.Serve("/fs", static.LocalFile("./filesys", false)))

// followed by other routes definition such as R.GET()
```

I also want to guard access by using a authentication middleware, without affecting other routes. I imagine it's something I need to do with Gin's group like this:

```
r := gin.New()
g := r.Group("/fs")
{ // what is the purpose of this parenthesis BTW?
    g.Use(authMiddleWare)
    g.Use(static.Serve("/fs", static.LocalFile(fileUploadDir, false)))
}
```

However, I can't get it to work. It is not routed in. If I do additional `g.GET` afterward, the path came out to be wrong.

How to go about this?

Comment: try request resources by `/fs/fs/xxx`

Comment: @huggie i deleted my answer seems to be a issue already opened on git 3 years ago https://github.com/gin-contrib/static/issues/14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I checked this issue has been open for 3 years on git with no solution for 3 years and the static package seems not being maintained anymore

This is an alternate solution that might help you

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    grp := r.Group("/static")
    {
        grp.StaticFS("", http.Dir("/your_directory"))
    }
    r.Run()
}
```